# Samsung Internet not working with App Links? Are other browsers/devices also incompatible?

Tags: android, deep-linking, samsung-internet

In my app when I try to use my app link from Google Chrome it works perfectly, but when I use Samsung Internet I find that the deep links don't work, and the URLs open in the browser instead.

Is there a list of compatible/incompatible internet browsers and/or phones that do not support Android App Links?

Or is there something potentially wrong with my app links implementation?

Comment: App Link is for opening your app, Deep Link is for opening your app and navigate to specified page (destination). Which one you're refering to?

Comment: I am also having this problem. In chrome, the app opens normally with the app link, but in Samsung Internet browser, you have to select and open it. Did you solve this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unlike iOS that pushes hard to the use of Universal Links, Google doesn't do that and therefore any browser on Android can decide if they want to use App Links or not.

Most of the browsers usually blocks the use of App Links so there is a need for URI scheme as a fallback to make sure users will get to your app correctly.

Answer (score 0):

I know there is already correct answer for the question. But I had this same issue with Samsung Internet and was able to solve it by enabling

`Settings > Internet Settings > Open links in other apps`

[image]

Hope this tip might help someone who see the question in the future.

Comment: since this is stackoverflow (and not some customer service website for android), i assume he needs a general solution that can scale to unknown users